# Finding Linear Matrix Transformation Formula Given Initial Conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T:  \ \ \mathbb R^3$ -> $\mathbb R^2$ be a linear transformation satisfying:

$$T([1,0,1]) = [2,3], \ \ \ T([2,1,3])=[-1,0], \ \ \ T([0,0,1])=[3,7]$$

Find $\ \ T([x,y,z])$.

I have started off by using the property: $$T(a+b+c) = T(a) + T(b) + T(c)$$ and resulted with: $$T([2,1,3]) = [4,10]$$

I next wrote it in the form $$T(x)=Ax$$

How can I solve for A to get the transformation formula. Am I on the right track? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a linear transformation, you can write $T$ as a matrix
$$A=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \end{array} \right)$$
Starting from your last condition $T([0,0,1])=[3,7]$, meaning that 
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
3 \\ 7 \end{array} \right)$$
It means that $c=3$ and $f=7$. You can follow with the other two conditions in order to determine the rest of the coefficients in a similar way. Let me know if you have problems to finish it

Answer (score 0):

You can use $A=\begin{bmatrix} T(e_1)&T(e_2)&T(e_3)\end{bmatrix}$
where $e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},e_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}, e_3=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, and

$\hspace{.4 in}e_1=v_1-v_3$ and $e_2=v_2-2v_1-v_3$ where
$v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}, v_2=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\3\end{bmatrix}$, and $v_3=e_3$;

so $T(e_1)=\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}3\\7\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-4\end{bmatrix}$ and $T(e_2)=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\end{bmatrix}-2\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}3\\7\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-8\\-13\end{bmatrix}$

---

Alternatively, $\;\;A\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0\\0&1&0\\1&3&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&3\\3&0&7\end{bmatrix}$, so

$\hspace{.3 in}A=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&3\\3&0&7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0\\0&1&0\\1&3&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&3\\3&0&7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&0\\0&1&0\\-1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-8&3\\-4&-13&7\end{bmatrix}$